# Convert long to wchar_t *

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++

thanks for reading.

I think I'm close on this one, but I could use some expertise on understanding why my attempt at something is not performing the way I expect it to.

What I need (for now) is to convert a type long (LONG, since I'm actually in VC++, but I know that's just a typedef) into a wchar_t *. I'm able to obtain the result I want but I'm unable to understand why the approach I think should work...isn't working. Here's the code that achieves the result I want:

```
const std::wstring myString{ std::to_wstring(wRect.bottom) };
const wchar_t * myCharPointer{ myString.c_str() };
```

Vs the approach I would like to take:

```
const wchar_t * lWind{ std::to_wstring(wRect.bottom).c_str() };
```

Using my debugger in VS Community I've determined that myCharPointer points to the correct value ("600"), but lWind gets assigned to point (or perhaps never gets a new assignment at all?) to a null string/empty string.

I'm curious about the theoretical performance aspect of these two approaches, i.e. using 2 lines of code and 2 different types of variables to arrive at the value I want vs. 1 line of code. Obviously there's some backend code that gets called to perform each of these approaches but I'm unsure if one approach is more performance costly than the other.

I'd appreciate any feedback people have about this; its very likely I'm missing something obvious and that the overall goal I'm trying to achieve may even be done in a better way but for now I'd like to satisfy my curiosity. Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually mean you want to create a string of `wchar_t` characters containing base 10 representation of the number?  or what?

Comment: The function I'm passing lWind to requires a wchar_t * parameter. Specifically, its the DrawText() function from the DirectWrite library. I'm using the DirectWrite library to operate as a debug overlay and I've set up an Debug Overlay update function that accepts a wchar_t * parameter of the text that will show in the overlay. In this particular case, I'm trying to relay numerical values to get displayed on the overlay using the DrawText() function.

If you're familiar with this library or have suggestions on ways to optimize what I'm attempting I'm very much open to suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to_wstring returns a wstring by value. The destructor of the temporary object gets called after calling c_str, when it loses scope on the next line, and then the pointer becomes invalid.

```
const wchar_t * lWind{ std::to_wstring(wRect.bottom).c_str() }; // after this line invalid pointer
```

You can fix it by storing a temporary string which lives as long as the wchar_t pointer.

```
std::wstring ws = std::to_wstring(100);

const wchar_t * lWind{ ws.c_str() };
```

Comment: I figured this might have been the case. Thanks for the confirmation. I tried following along the trace but...I'm still familiarizing myself with C++ and wasn't able to grasp what exactly was going on.